# How to sort tuple twice

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

for example,

```
a = [(4, 3), (6, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

how to sort this tuple twice without using `itemgetter`?
I want sort by first `key = a[1]` and second `key = a[0]`.
Like this,

```
a = [(6, 3), (4, 3), (3, 1), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: Why twice, and why without itemgetter? You'd get what you want with **one pass** using `itemgetter(0, 1)`.

Comment: Besides, **that's the default sort**, just reverse.

Comment: It'd help if you actually included an example input list that'd sort *differently* if the second element was ignored. Or even would produce an order that differs from the input order when you sort on just the second element of the tuple..

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the sort:

```
sorted(a, reverse=True)
```

for a new list or

```
a.sorted(reverse=True)
```

to sort the  list in-place.

Tuples are compared lexicographically, so first by the first element, then the second in case of a tie. Sorting first by the second element, then the first, would result in *exactly the same order* as if you first sorted by the second element and sorted the resulting list by the first:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = [(4, 3), (6, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[(4, 3), (6, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
>>> sorted(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True), key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
[(6, 3), (4, 3), (3, 1), (2, 1)]
>>> sorted(a, reverse=True)
[(6, 3), (4, 3), (3, 1), (2, 1)]
```

If you input has tuples with more than two elements where those extra elements must be ignored, you can *still use `itemgetter()`*, because it supports multiple indices (at which point it returns a tuple of the values at those indices):

```
>>> itemgetter(0, 1)(a[0])
(4, 3)
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0, 1), reverse=True)
[(6, 3), (4, 3), (3, 1), (2, 1)]
```